# Compare data for two versions of the same MySQL database table

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL tables that have the exact same structure and mostly the same data. Some of the rows would be different between the two because my client updated the old website instead of the new website. There are hundreds of records and a column is not in place for the last modified date. I have created a new database on localhost and imported the old and new tables. All of the rows of data will need to be compared and differences between the old and new databases will need to be returned. Once the differences are identified, would there be a way to easily migrate the updated data from the old table to the new table? I am a MySQL novice, but I can usually muddle my way through issues. Thanks in advance for your assistance.

I have been looking at the following code, but I am not sure if it is the best answer.

```
SELECT *,'table_1' AS o FROM table_1
UNION
SELECT *,'table_2' AS o FROM table_2
WHERE some_id IN (
    SELECT some_id
    FROM (
        SELECT * FROM table_1
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM table_2
    ) AS x
    GROUP BY some_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
 )
 ORDER BY some_id, o;
```

Comment: "mostly the same data" is really not enough information to know how the data might vary and what steps you would want to take to reconcile the two.

I think it's very unlikely that you'll be able to have one command that gets you all of the information that you need.

Do these tables have a unique id field? If so, are there going to be overlaps between rows with the same id but different data? Do you want to have the final table have all the data between both tables, even if the unique id isn't always consistent? I think it might be tough to help without more information.

Comment: @mrcheshire The two tables will only have a few rows that contain different information. Each table uses the same unique primary id and these would be the same between both tables. Yes, the rows will have the same id, but different values for some of the other rows. Example rows that could be different would be "organization" and "address". I would just like to see what was changed in the old table, so I could manually update it in the new table. Hope this clarifies a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.  You are finding the primary keys for all rows where the every value is the same across both tables in the subselect used in the where clause.  You then exclude rows with those primary keys from the unioned result set.  Now how you go about reconciling the differences is a totally different story :)

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, 'table 1' FROM table_1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *, 'table 2' FROM table_2
) AS combined
WHERE combined.primary_key_field
NOT IN (
    SELECT t1.primary_key_field
    FROM table_1 AS t1
    INNER JOIN table_2 AS t2
    ON t1.primary_key_field = t2.primary_key_field
    AND t1.some_other_field = t2.some_other_field
    AND ... /* join on all fields in tables */
)
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be getting me the results I need.

Answer (score 0):

A `insert into select` single query will do.

```
insert into table_new
select * from table_old
where some_id NOT IN (select some_id from table_new)
```